# SilverStripe wysiwyg style constraints

Tags: php, tinymce, wysiwyg, silverstripe

Is there any way to prevent certain custom wysiwyg styles to be applied to certain HTML elements?

Suppose I have two styles called "red" and "framed". One colours text red and the latter puts a frame around photos.

Can I control which styles are available when highlighting text or an image? For example, I want the style "framed" not to be available when highlighting text and the style "red" not showing in the styles dropdown menu when highlighting an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tinymce configuration is kinda tricky in silverstripe, though it looks easy once you got it running.

Jonom wrote down some configs and put it on Github, called  [tinytidy](https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-tinytidy) module, [there you might find a possile solution](https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-tinytidy/blob/master/_config.php#L19). So best is to try out this module as it adds some custom css to the editor.

Copied from there, put in your */mysite/_config.php*:

```
$formats = array(

    // Define the styles that will be available in TinyMCE's dropdown style menu
    // * Use 'selector' to specify which elements a style can be applied to
    // * See Headings example below for explanation of different settings
    // * Using 'classes' allows a class to be combined with others while 'attributes'=>'style' removes other classes before applying
    // Text styles

    array(
        'title' => 'Selected text'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'highlight red',
        'classes' => 'red',
        'inline' => 'span',
        'selector' => 'i,em,b,strong,a'
    ),

    array(
        'title' => 'Images',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Put a frame around a photo',
        'attributes' => array('class'=>'framed'),
        'selector' => 'img'
    )
);
//Set the dropdown menu options
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOption('style_formats',$formats);
```

hope that helps, wmk